# Javascript Hex Escaped String returned to Cocoa App without Escaped Characters

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uiwebview

Part of an iPhone application that I'm developing is using a *UIWebView* to get the *onclick* event for certain elements on a page.  One issue which has cropped up is on certain pages, like the iPhone version of http://news.google.com, the page has already hex escaped the links like in the following:

```
javascript:window.open('/news/url?sa\x3dt\x26ct3\x3dMAA4CEgAUABgAWoCdXN6AWjYAQE\x26usg\x3dAFQjCNGUV1AFw0LsmkcQzNnvo69ma_dhhA\x26rt\x3dHOMEPAGE\x26url\x3dhttp://www.cnn.com/2010/US/11/30/wikileaks/?hpt%3DSbin');void(0);
```

When I receive the function from the *UIWebView* using the following method:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SomeFunction(%i,%i);",(NSInteger)pt.x,(NSInteger)pt.y]]
```

I receive back a String with the escaped characters in it as actual characters.  So I receive back from the above method the javascript call with the hex escapes instead of:

```
javascript:window.open('/news/url?sa=t&ct3=MAA4CEgAUABgAWoCdXN6AWjYAQE&usg=AFQjCNGUV1AFw0LsmkcQzNnvo69ma_dhhA&rt=HOMEPAGE&url=http://www.cnn.com/2010/US/11/30/wikileaks/?hpt%3DSbin');void(0);
```

I have tried all sorts of methods of escaping the String in Javascript like percent escaping and URIEncoding/URIDecoding but it does not seem to work, just keeps sending the escaped string instead of the actual characters.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Wait, where does the example string ("javascript:window.open...") come into it? Is that what `SomeFunction` is supposed to return?

Comment: javascript:window.open is part of the `onclick` attribute of some element in the DOM tree.  It is returned by the `SomeFunction` but it is currently returning them with the escaping characters as individual characters rather than the character they are supposed to represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to make use of [CFStringTransform](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableStringRef/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringTransform) if you replace the "\x" escapes with "\u00" escapes:

```
NSMutableString* js = [ [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                               @"SomeFunction(%i,%i);",
                                               (NSInteger)pt.x,(NSInteger)pt.y]
                         ] mutableCopy];
[js replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\x" 
                    withString:@"\\u00" 
                       options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch 
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, [js length])];
CFStringTransform((CFMutableStringRef)js,
                  NULL, 
                  (CFStringRef)@"Any-Hex/Java", 
                  true);
```

I'm not certain which (if any) iOS versions support the "Any-Hex/Java" [transliterator](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general#TOC-General). Additionally, the above won't handle some strings properly; any substring with an even number of backslashes before the "x" will be erroneously decoded.

Comment: Any-Hex/Java worked for me on iOS 4.0.  I'm not sure how it would have worked on earlier versions.  Thanks very much!

Comment: If 4.0 supports it, I expect it will work on 3, and probably even on 2, as support for both ICU transformations and the "Any-Hex/Java" were added at the same time to OS X. Not that I would place money on it.